# Pass a query in URL using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass a $_GET[''] to a php file, when a word is clicked in a div,it must display data from the db.

It displays the data without the query.

The process.php contains SQL statement to query the db and display values.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: What is your problem? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are serious, read [`.ajax();`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [.get();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Example:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```